# android how to get refresh rate

Tags: android, refresh, android-animation

```
public void animateScreenOn() {
    CellLayout layout = (CellLayout) getChildAt(getCurrentPage());
    if (layout != null) {
        int count = layout.getPageChildCount();
        for (int i = count-1;  i>=0;  i--) {
            View v = layout.getPageChild(i);
            v.setScaleX(0.95f);
            v.setScaleY(0.95f);

            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            ObjectAnimator animation1 = LauncherAnimUtils.ofPropertyValuesHolder(v, 
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.0f));
            animation1.setDuration(1000L);
            animation1.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

            ObjectAnimator animation2 = LauncherAnimUtils.ofPropertyValuesHolder(v, 
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.0f));
            animation2.setDuration(500L);
            animation2.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

            List<Animator> items = new ArrayList<Animator>();
            items.add(animation1);
            items.add(animation2);

            set.playTogether(items);
            set.setStartDelay((count-1-i)*100L);
            set.start();
        }
    }
}
```

this code have an issue. the time of this code cost is different on different devices, some is ok, but some will be too short, so i need to change animate time depend on device refresh rate. anyone can tell me how to get it from android code, 3X!